# Uploading photos to google photos

Tags: google-photos

I have over 22gb of photos to be uploaded to google photos. I have 2 options, upload photos through website or use google backup and sync app.

My question is does using app speedup things and save data by doing some compression sort of thing on the device itself?

Comment: Is this from a desktop PC or a mobile device?

Comment: On a mobile device, Google Photos does compress your images and videos and that's how they offer free unlimited storage on Google Photos. The original quality is reduced in free tier. On the other hand, if you have a premium subscription, like Google One, let's say, you can then upload all your photos at original quality. Read the details here https://www.phonearena.com/news/Google-Photos-High-quality-vs-Original-Whats-the-difference-and-should-you-care_id93938

Comment: ^ I have a 110GB Google One account, and confirm the images aren't compressed.

Comment: You may find an authoritative answer through http://webapps.stackexchange.com